# create a column in r based on a condition involving another column

Tags: r

I want to create a new column in my data set containing the proficiency level of students based on their grade in a test. So, if students grade was between 0 and 10, then the level assigned to them should be A1, if the grade is between 11 and 16, the level assigned should be A2 and so on. How to code this in R? I've tried the code below. The new column was created, but containing only the level A1. So, the condition did not work. Can anyone help me with that?

```
    data$CatEnglishTest=as.factor(ifelse(data$EnglishTestGrade %in% 
data$EnglishTestGrade<=10,'A1',
                               ifelse(data$EnglishTestGrade %in% data$EnglishTestGrade > 10 
&& data$EnglishTestGrade < 15,'A2',
                                      as.character(data$EnglishTestGrade))))
```

Comment: This probably has to do with `data$EnglishTestGrade<=10` . If you would make this and the other condition like `data[data$EnglishTestGrade <= 10,]$Grade` it should work.

Comment: Where to add in this code the level such as "A1" , "A2", etc?

Comment: Could you make a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will certainly help answering.

Comment: I have made a small example and showed how you can use the code, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(EnglishTestGrade = c(0, 5, 10, 14, 20)) 

data <- mutate(data, 
               CatEnglishTest = case_when(
                 EnglishTestGrade <= 10 ~ "A1",
                 EnglishTestGrade < 15  ~ "A2",
                 TRUE ~ "Undefined category"
               ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the students scores in

```
scores <- data.frame(student=paste("ID",1:10),score = seq(10,100,10))

   student score
1     ID 1    10
2     ID 2    20
3     ID 3    30
4     ID 4    40
5     ID 5    50
6     ID 6    60
7     ID 7    70
8     ID 8    80
9     ID 9    90
10   ID 10   100
```

And the grading scale in

```
scale <- data.frame(score = seq(0,100,25), grade = LETTERS[5:1])

  score grade
1     0     E
2    25     D
3    50     C
4    75     B
5   100     A
```

Then you could use this code to assign each student a grade

```
scores$grades <- scale$grade[sapply(scores$score, function(x) tail(which(x >= scale$score),1))]

   student score grades
1     ID 1    10      E
2     ID 2    20      E
3     ID 3    30      D
4     ID 4    40      D
5     ID 5    50      C
6     ID 6    60      C
7     ID 7    70      C
8     ID 8    80      B
9     ID 9    90      B
10   ID 10   100      A
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a little example DF.

```r
EnglishTestGrade <- sample(1:20,20)
Student <- LETTERS[1:20]
data <- data.frame(EnglishTestGrade, Student)
str(data)
#> 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ EnglishTestGrade: int  1 15 19 12 3 14 8 16 2 18 ...
#>  $ Student         : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...


data$CatEnglishTest <- ifelse(data$EnglishTestGrade %in%
  data[data$EnglishTestGrade <= 10,]$EnglishTestGrade, 'A1',
    ifelse(data$EnglishTestGrade %in% 
             (data[data$EnglishTestGrade > 10,]$EnglishTestGrade &
             data[data$EnglishTestGrade < 15,]$EnglishTestGrade), 'A2', 
           as.character(data$EnglishTestGrade)
  )
)
#> Warning in data[data$EnglishTestGrade > 10, ]$EnglishTestGrade & data[data$EnglishTestGrade < : Länge des längeren Objektes
#>       ist kein Vielfaches der Länge des kürzeren Objektes
data
#>    EnglishTestGrade Student CatEnglishTest
#> 1                 1       A             A1
#> 2                15       B             15
#> 3                19       C             19
#> 4                12       D             12
#> 5                 3       E             A1
#> 6                14       F             14
#> 7                 8       G             A1
#> 8                16       H             16
#> 9                 2       I             A1
#> 10               18       J             18
#> 11                9       K             A1
#> 12               10       L             A1
#> 13                7       M             A1
#> 14                4       N             A1
#> 15               11       O             11
#> 16               17       P             17
#> 17               20       Q             20
#> 18               13       R             13
#> 19                6       S             A1
#> 20                5       T             A1
```